# Problem on The Multiplication Operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f$ be a bounded measurable function on $X$ and $M_f$ be the multiplication operator on $L^2$($\mu$).Then prove that $\int$ $fdP=M_f$ where $P$ is the $spectral$ $measure$. I have been trying for a long time to prove this result simply by using the definition of spectral measure and the definition of $\int$ $fdP$ which is defined as the bounded linear map arising from the sesquilinear form
($x$,$y$)$\longmapsto\int$ $fdP_{x,y}$ where $P_{x,y}(E)=<x,P(E)y>$.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the operator $A=\int \lambda dP(\lambda)$? You haven't been clear about what operator $P$ is the spectral measure for. I think that may be part of the confusion.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.The question is a bit ambiguous and it is not clear what is P. I also faced similar problems. But then I realized that P is the usual spectral measure given by multiplication by the indicator function and using that I finally managed to solve this. Thanks for trying to help me out.